Are there ways to trade differences in distribution between (or within) assets?
It's common enough to examine asset returns, or grouped subset asset returns, compare across them and make some investment decision, either directionally or via a spread/relative value trade.
Can do something similar with the second moment, whereby, for instance, like to like the options on an asset with higher vol will be more expensive than one with lower vol.  More pointedly, if an asset has a LT volatility of 20% and we see it's 30d rolling SD spike to 30%, we could sell its volatility by writing call or put options with the expectation its premiums would revert lower once its vol returned to normal (again, ignoring the impacts of greeks, other inputs, etc).
Is there a corollary though for higher momemnts (eg, skew, kurtosis)?
For instance, for a given asset, say I quintile based on some exogenous factor (eg, v high/high/med/low/v low volatility regimes) and plot density functions for each subset's daily change in price.  In a situation where there was no meaningful or impactful info represented in the exogenous var, I'd expect PDFs to look pretty similar, like this:

But say it looked like this--where density for the v high vol group had a distribution noticeably different from the others:

Taking as given the differences are meaningful, what would the trade be (trading based on the fact one group shows more 'skew' than the others and not just based on having a negative mean where others are close to 0)?  Same question for the fourth moment--one subgroup shows higher peak/fatter tails (or the inverse) than the others, what's the trade?

Not really my area of expertise but just an idea: Carr-Madan says you can create any European payoff using a linear combination of standard European put/call options. You then short a portfolio that mimics a normal distribution (or whatever you think the market thinks), and long a portfolio that mimics the distribution you think the underlying will take.

@Rylan, thanks for that.  You have a link to reference or paper that shows this per chance?

http://pricing.online.fr/docs/TradingVolatilityStrat.pdf Here you go -- as a caveat, I haven't read this paper in ages so I don't remember much beyond the formula, so what I suggested might be useless

I also realized I'm missing a word in my comment earlier, it says "You then short a..." which makes it sound like they recommend it, what I meant is "You could then short a..." which is much less strong and comes with no implied recommendation from Carr or Madan :-)

@Rylan, all good, adjacent ideas are as a good a place to start as anything...thanks!
